# Python, finding more than one index in a list of letters

Tags: python, loops, indexing

So I'm just beginning learning python and am creating a hangman game for a project. I am stuck.let me give you some background.

I got the program to get rid of the letters in the alphabet, and add them to the blank spaces for the word that's being guessed, but it will only find the index of the first letter. So lets say the word I am trying to guess is failsafe. Now lets say I guess the letter f. It returns f _ _ _ _ _ _ _ instead of f _ _ _ _ _ f _. It seems to me that the for loop is stopping once it finds the first instance of the letter in the list and breaking there. I need to find and display all instance of the letter.

Code:

```
def makechoice(list)
    # defines the word trying to be guessed as a list of letters
    Global listword
    #defines the amount of blanks in listword as a list "_ "
    global blanks
    #user input to guess a letter
    current = raw_input("Please enter your guess:")
    for a in listword:
        if a == current:
            t = listword.index(a)
            #puts the letter and a blank in place of the unoccupied space if it is a match.
            blanks[t] = str(listword[t]) + " "
```

No is it just me or shouldn't this loop through all the letters in listword and if it finds 2 "f"s display them both. Please someone help. I've done research and can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.index index returns only the first occurance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.index()` returns the first index of the given character. If the word has the same character multiple times it will only ever return the first index (unless you explicitly specify a start offset).

When you need access to the index during iteration you should use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
for i, x in enumerate(listword):
    # i is the index, x is the character
    if x == current:
        blanks[i] = listword[i] + " "
```

Comment: No it will not. We can use the second parameter in `index` function. Please check my answer.

Comment: In that case it returns the first index of the character after the given offset. It still returns after finding the first occurrence.

Comment: True. But `it will only ever return the first index` might make people think otherwise.

Comment: I used the answer below and it worked perfectly. I am going to test this one as well. Can you explain the enumerate() a little more. Not sure I get what it is doing. Is it just changing the list position to its index value?

Comment: `enumerate` will allow you to keep track of the current loop index, which means you no longer need to use `listword.index()` to find out where you are up to. If `listword` is `"hello"`, in the first iteration of the loop `i=0, x='h'`, in the second `i=1, x='e'` etc. You can then use `i` and `x` as you please.

Comment: Thanks! This worked as well and seems like cleaner code to me. This helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the second argument in `index` function to specify the starting index to search for the character.

```
data = "Welcome to ohio"
t = -1
while True:
    try:
        t = data.index("o", t + 1)
        print t
    except ValueError:
        break
```

**Output**

```
4
9
11
14
```

Comment: I used this answer first and it worked perfectly. I just adapted it to my code. Thanks so much that really helped!

Answer (score 1):

or use finditer in re package:

```
import re
[x.start() for x in re.finditer("f", "failsafe")]
```

Output: [0, 6]

Answer (score 0):

I'd leave those extra spaces out until you're printing the word

```
>>> listword = "failsafe"
>>> blanks = list('_' * len(listword))
>>> guess = 'f'
>>> for i, j in enumerate(listword):
...     if j == guess:
...         blanks[i] = j
... 
>>> print " ".join(blanks)
f _ _ _ _ _ f _
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got my answer above, but I really like the blanks = list("_ " * len(listword)). I did a for x in range len (listword + 1) so that really helps clean up my code a bit. :)